# MySQL: Conditional to run Query 1 or Query 2 based on a certain field

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a trigger which is supposed to run **Query 1** if the value of the field `statuscode` from the newly inserted row is 200. But if the `statuscode` is say 300 run **Query 2** instead. Is this at all possible in MySQL?

I tried the first thing which came to mind but it's obviously wrong.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT ON tableA
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF(new.statuscode = 200,
        (DELETE FROM tableB WHERE new.guid = tableB.guid),
        (UPDATE tableB SET is_complete = 0 WHERE new.guid = tableB.guid))
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for IF/ELSE in mysql procedures is:

```
IF (NEW.statuscode = 200) THEN
   DELETE FROM tableB WHERE new.guid = tableB.guid;
ELSE
   UPDATE tableB SET is_complete = 0 WHERE new.guid = tableB.guid;
END IF;
```

Here are the docs for trigger syntax: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have your IF syntax wrong. If statements should have a THEN and ENDIF keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

I haven't used MySQL in 6 months or so, so hopefully this syntax is right:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT ON tableA
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.statuscode = 200  THEN
        DELETE FROM tableB WHERE new.guid = tableB.guid;
    ELSE 
        UPDATE tableB SET is_complete = 0 WHERE new.guid = tableB.guid;
    END IF;
END
```